# Is gdm3 launched twice?

Tags: gnome-shell, gdm

I use Ubuntu 18.04 with Gnome Shell and gdm3.

When I press <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + F1</kbd> I see gdm3 home screen. My current desktop session is on the second "screen" <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + F2</kbd>.

Is it a bug?

I had a random bug and I don't know if it's related to the duplicate gdm3 instances: when I logged back after locking my screen, I was unable to reopen with session and I had to reboot the computer by pressing <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + Del</kbd> on another screen, like <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + F3</kbd>.

I removed gdm3 with `sudo apt remove --purge gdm3` and reinstalled it and there are still 2 instances.

Update: once my screen is locked, sometimes I can't log in again as my password is rejected, but if I switch to the first "screen" with <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + F1</kbd> I can log in again.